# jquery json parsing from remote host

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to get json data from a remote host with the following code. But failing, I am using jquery get json

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#driver").click(function(event){
      $.getJSON('http://108.167.132.194/~softnet/json.php?callback=?', function(jd) {
         $('#stage').html('<p> Name: ' + jd.name + '</p>');
         $('#stage').append('<p>Password : ' + jd.password+ '</p>');

      });
  });
});

</script>
```

When i try to get data from localhost it works perfectly

Comment: What response does the server give you? I can see you're using JSONP so it's probably not a cross domain issue.

Comment: Maybe a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) matter? Check the console messages in the browser.

Comment: what language are you using server side?

Comment: might be worth looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp

Comment: You are working with json.php, its response has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into cross-domain ajax call. What you are trying to do will not work directly. You will either have to use JSONP or add the ips/hosts to allowed domain list.

What I can see from your client side code is that you are using JSONP but your server side does not support it. You need to implement it on also on the server side to support JSNOP.

Comment: Where should i enter these details, I am already using callback

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to wrap the response in a callback so the browser doesn't instantly evaluate it. The callback parameter should then be set to the name of the callback that is returned.